# Детали работы с круговой диаграммой matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Как включить отображение значений поверх их частей (?) в круговой диаграмме в matplotlib?

Не процентная составляющая, а именно значение (!!!)

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def absolute_value(val):
    a  = numpy.round(val/100.*slices.sum(), 3)
    return a

slices = numpy.array([58.01, 6.77, 32, 124, 33.45])

activities = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
cols = ['gold', 'yellowgreen', 'lightcoral', 'lightskyblue', 'orangered']

plt.pie(slices, labels=activities,autopct=absolute_value,colors=cols,startangle=140,shadow=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]